# BPEL Add-on

Tags: bpel

I´m not sure if this is the right place to ask, however..... 
I need help from someone who has experience in Modeling BPEL Diagrams. I´m thinking of writing an Add-on for a BPEL Modeling tool. I want to write some Add-on, which really is useful to the Business Analysts.  I´m playing around with the idea of simulating and testing the BPEL Diagrams. Is there something more useful.....what do you think of the idea to transform UML to BPEL (bottom up approach)....please give me some feedback

Answer (score 2):

There are some opensource Graphical BPEL Editors like [Eclipse BPEL Editor](http://www.eclipse.org/bpel/), it is better if you can improve and contribute to these tools rather than starting from the scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Graphical modeling: good. WS-BPEL is XML, which is painstaking to write by hand at the best of times.  There is no standard graphical notation, though.

Simulation: I'm all in favor of simulation, but simulating *what*?  Performance?  Functionality?

Comment: I already got a Graphical Interface, so I thought it is a good idea to simulate the workflow like it is possible in Aris